# how to set TOS flag using websockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, payload, java-websocket

i want to use websockets in my java application, but have to specify the TOS flag. Is there a common way to do this properly? how do i configure socket settings typically? 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the `setTrafficClass(int)` method from the `java.net.Socket` class. The JavaDoc has a good description of the allowed parameter values and what it refers to:

> For Internet Protocol v4 the value consists of an octet with precedence and TOS fields as detailed in RFC 1349. The TOS field is bitset created by bitwise-or'ing values such the following :-
>
> • IPTOS_LOWCOST (0x02)
>
> • IPTOS_RELIABILITY (0x04)
>
> • IPTOS_THROUGHPUT (0x08)
>
> • IPTOS_LOWDELAY (0x10)
>
> The last low order bit is always ignored as this corresponds to the MBZ (must be zero) bit.

Comment: thank you, yes, but how do i reach the socket from jetty?